# Cannot edit excel workbook in Excel Web App

Tags: document-library, owa

In our SharePoint 2013 we use OWA. We can open documents in it, but when we try edit excel workbook (old files and also new) in EWA, it shows box with text:

You can create a copy in a supported format to edit the workbook in the browser. (it is translated by Google Translator)

But in last it was ok. I think, that it isn't same problem [like this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin/excel-online-unsupported-features-shapes-or-other/804db420-225b-45e8-890d-e81bcae2e533). I did not find any similar problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

So issue is resolved. Problem was in licencing of OWA editing. After migrate to new farm, we don't have set OfficeWebAppsEdit as it is describe in [this post](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/enabling-licensing-and-editing-for-office-web-apps-in-sharepoint-2013/). Also when we wanted edit Word, it shows box with this text:

Unfortunately, you are not licensed to edit document files using word web app.

Maybe this will help someone else:)